# sleep() / Sleep() behaviors in Linux / Windows

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("\nHello");
    sleep(5);
    printf("\nLinux");
}
```

In my expectation, It should be like:

```
PRINT Hello --- WAIT 5 SECS ---> PRINT Linux
```

But actually it will be like this:

```
WAIT 5 SECS --> PRINT Hello --> PRINT Linux
```

Why ? How to make my program be the first one (as my expectation) ?

**And why my code can run expectedly on Win32 Console?**

Comment: 'cause console output isn't buffered in Windows

Answer (score 4):

Your stream is line-buffered, as you don't end your string with `\n`, flush it using `fflush`.

Change your program to:

```
int main()
{
    printf("\nHello");
    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(5);
    printf("\nLinux");
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works now, but why my code can run expectedly on Win32 Console? Microsoft problem?

Comment: @KevinDongNaiJia if the stream is fully buffered it will work without the `fflush` if it is line-buffered you'll need the `fflush`. Use `fflush` to have the same behavior on different configurations.

Answer (score 1):

The output is buffered and is not printed until newline.

Try with:

```
printf("\nHello\n");
sleep(5);
printf("Linux");
```